# How to get the subitem value from a TRESTReponse in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, response, firemonkey

I need to get the `subitem1` value of a `LResponse` that contains following JSON:

```js
"Information": {
    "subitem1": "2011",
    "subitem2": "Test"
}
```

I am using this code to get the other values, it's working good, but when I try to get the `Information`, `subitem1` or `subitem2`, it's returning a empty value.

```
var
  LClient: TRESTClient;
  LRequest: TRESTRequest;
  LResponse: TRESTResponse;
begin
  LClient := TRESTClient.Create(URL_API);
  try
    LRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(LClient);
    try
      LResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(LClient);
      try
        LRequest.Client := LClient;
        LRequest.Response := LResponse;
        LRequest.Method := rmGET;
        LRequest.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+FToken);
        LRequest.Params.ParameterByName('Authorization').Options := [poDoNotEncode];
        LRequest.Params.AddHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        LRequest.Execute;

        LResponse.GetSimpleValue('subitem1', FLogradouro);
        { ... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetSimpleValue` is only able to read top level properties of JSON in response. It is also extremely inefficient, because it parses JSON upon every call to the method.

`TRESTResponse` already gives you access to parsed JSON via its [`JSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.JSONValue) property. It allows you to query values within the whole structure using JSON path. Accessing `JSONValue` property will parse the response only once, but beware that it can return nil, if the response is empty or not a valid JSON.

Another point is that you don't have to create `TRestResponse` yourself. It is automatically created in `LRequest.Execute`. With that said the code to access values in the returned JSON would be:

```
if not Assigned(LRequest.Response.JSONValue) then
  raise Exception.Create('Invalid response.');
ShowMessage(LRequest.Response.JSONValue.GetValue<string>('Information.subitem1'));
```

You can use square brackets in JSON path as array accessor to access items by index:

```
LRequest.Response.JSONValue.GetValue<string>('SomeStrings[0]');
```

Comment: I think you forgot to access the `JSONValue` property before calling `GetValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
RESTResponse1.JSONValue.GetValue<string>('Information.subitem1');
```

or

```
var
  LValue: string;
  LJSONObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  LJSONObject := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
  LValue := LJSONObject.GetValue('subitem1').Value;
end;
```